# Ruby delegator. Call method defined outside class/module: NameError

Tags: ruby

I have an issue with `Delegator` which turns out to be an issue with `Kernel.respond_to?` or `Kernel.instance_method`

```
def some_func
  puts '12'
end

puts ::Kernel.respond_to?(:some_func, true) #=> true
::Kernel.instance_method(:some_func) #=> `instance_method': undefined method `some_func' for module `Kernel' (NameError)
```

Originally found in this scenario:

```
def some_func
  puts '12'
end

class Klass < Delegator
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def __getobj__
    @obj
  end

  def func
    some_func #=> `instance_method': undefined method `some_func' for module `Kernel' (NameError)
  end
end

Klass.new(0).func
```

I guess that `Kernel.respond_to?(:some_func)` is true because indeed we can call it on `Kernel`. And `instance_method` tries to take a method defined on `Kernel` itself (which is not in this case).

But I'm wondering why `Delegator` uses `Kernel.respond_to?` to check if the methid exists and `Kernel.instance_method` to call it? (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/delegate.rb#L85)

-= update =- 
I've created an issue in Ruby bugtracker https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12113

Comment: That code produces the correct result for me in Ruby 2.3.0.

Comment: So you copy-pasted this code and run it without errors? That's very strange. What OS are you using?

Comment: OS is hardly ever a factor for simple code like this. Are you using Ruby 2 or better?

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the wrong spot. When you define a method like that it doesn't show up under `instance_methods`, you're not dealing with an *instance of* Kernel, as that's a module, but instead here:

```
Kernel.methods & [ :some_func ]
# => [:some_func]
```

There it is.

Comment: The `method` method is used to get more information about a particular method, like `Kernel.method(:some_func).source_location`, but it also works in this case.

Comment: Yes, I know what it's for. OP asked why `Kernel.instance_method(:some_func)` didn't work, which your answer explains, but I wanted to point out that the equivalent to `instance_method` that *will* work in this situation is `method`.

Comment: @Jordan Oh, for sure! Was just clarifying there.

Comment: Then why Ruby's Delegator uses `instance_method` ? https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/delegate.rb#L85 Is this a bug or feature?